# Excel table join sql table

Tags: sql, excel, join

i have one table in Excel in Sheet1

and in Sheet2 second table from sql db.

I want to join this two table to get in first table column from second Sheet2.

I try

```
right click and merge
```

and when i need to select tables in drop down list i have only table from sql.

How to join this two sheets - excel table with sql table?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://superuser.com/questions/420635/how-do-i-join-two-worksheets-in-excel-as-i-would-in-sql

Comment: bu when i add new row in my first table in Sheet1 and do refresh a got only started data, not i add data

Comment: That would be a separate question,.